# How to add Calendar Event in android developing

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, android-calendar

I have tried some custom library for add & remove Calendar Event but i cant success .
Google said Android not provide calendar with add event so we can use custom library.
So how can i do ?

Comment: use google calendar api. Preferred

Comment: use the this lib.
https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar provides functionality to add an event on the local calendar.
You can use content Resolver to add an event on calendar programmatically without using intent.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

The CalendarContract.Events table contains details for individual events. To add, update, or delete events, an application must include the WRITE_CALENDAR permission in its manifest file.